# How to prevent auto-complete popup display after comma or colon?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

I just updated my Sublime Text version (Build 4107), and it seems to me a new behaviour appeared - that I would like to avoid.

Whenever I write a colon or comma, the auto-complete popup automatically displays, which is problematic because most of the time in this situation I am about to go to next line by pressing Enter. Thing is, if press Enter, I select now the first occurence of autocomplete instead of going to next line.

I can avoid this by doing "Alt + Enter" or by pressing "Esc" before Enter, but it is not a convenient solution. Is there any way to prevent this autocomplete popup to display afer this particular punctuation signs ?

I read about `punctuation.separator` scope naming (https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/scope_naming.html#punctuation). But I can't figure out how to use it in `auto_complete_foo` settings to do what I want.

Example :

[image: pop up after colon]

[image: pop up after comma]

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Just to double check, does this also happen in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a package SublimeCodeIntel, try to disable it, and check the problem is saved or not

It helped me

Answer (score 2):

You can set `"auto_complete_when_likely": false,` in your user preferences which should prevent this behavior.